# Making a query which selects the news that contain a specific word

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

```
       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
           title TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
           newsletter_description TEXT NOT NULL
       );
```

I need to write a query which selects all the `news` that contain the word "apple" or "watermelon"(or both) in their `title` or in their `newsletter_description` and I am not very sure about how I can do that. (case insensitive, it can also be "AppLe" or "WaterMelon")

Comment: I don't like this behaviour of accepting an answer and then un-accept but it's fine  and you have all rights to choose the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM NEWS
WHERE title LIKE "%apple%" OR 
      title LIKE "%watermelon%" OR
      newsletter_description LIKE "%apple%" OR 
      newsletter_description LIKE "%watermelon%
```

SQlite implemented LIKE operator case insensitive for ASCII characters by default. Unless you use unicode characters in your text you can use above query.

However if you use unicode chars, using lower or upper functions doesn't work either. So there is no point in using lower or upper functions at all.

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/strlike.html

[image]

Comment: your answer is quite detailed with respect to SQlite but instead of focusing on other answer whether it makes point or or not try telling the positive side of it and I am sure there is apart from `no point` part of not using `lower`

Comment: What i wanted to emphasize was case insensitivity of Sqlite. I saw people mention lower/upper function in many places in this thread. So, to prevent people having wrong impression/knowledge remain in their mind, I felt to mention it specifically. I don't have any other intention otherwise. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` operator and to have case insensitive search you can either use `lower` or `upper` on the actual column and also have to convert the input to lower/upper before passing to the query accordingly,

```
select * 
  from news 
 where lower(newsletter_description) like '%watermelon%' 
    or lower(newsletter_description) like '%apple%'
    or lower(title) like '%watermelon%' 
    or lower(title) like '%apple%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use « lower(title) like '%apple%' »
In fact the lower put all the field in minuscule, that help you to find the word needed without knowing how he is written

Comment: And how can I use it in order to find all of the words within the query, in other words, how the full query command would look like?

Comment: Select * from news where lower(title) like '%apple%' or lower(title) like '%watermelon%'. If you use a other where clause like a date or something else, put the request in parentheses like it : select * from ... where (lower(title) ... or lower(title)...) and date = '2020101'

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE that returns all the words that you search for and join it to the table:

```
with cte(word) as (values ('apple'), ('watermelon'))
select n.*
from news n inner join (select '%' || word || '%' word from cte) c
on n.title like c.word or n.newsletter_description like c.word
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive way will be select * from new where lower(title) like ‘%apple%’ or lower(title) like ‘%watermelon%’ or lower(newsletter_description) like ‘%apple%’ or lower(newsletter_description) like ‘%watermelon%’;